# make4ht breaks with text formatting in section headers when trying to convert to odt

Tags: sectioning, make4ht

I have a test file that I wish to convert to .odt. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\title{Special media for rapid germination of \textit{Persea americana} seeds using vitamin B\textsubscript{12}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle %This works without problems.
\section{Sections}
\subsection{B$_{12}$ in $Persea~americana$}% This works, but the formatting is incorrect.
\subsection{B\textsubscript{12} in \textit{Persea americana}}% This generates errors. Using \emph{} also doesn't help. Wrapping the offending pieces of text in \mbox{} doesn't help either.
\end{document}
```

that generates a pdf that looks like this:

[image: make4ht_sectioning]

However, when running the command: `make4ht -c config.cfg -f odt Test.tex`, I get the output:

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: Test.tex
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    ?    Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 8.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    ?    Emergency stop.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

I find that the formatting (`\textit{}`, `\textsubscript{}`, etc.) in the main document title seems to work for `make4ht`. However formatting in the sections and subsections, throws up errors. Using math-mode can help, but that is undesirable as it restricts which font one can use for their original document.

Also, the formatting in the output is incorrect. Using `\mbox{}` doesn't protect the formatting. Using alternatives to `\textit{}` such as `\emph{}` doesn't help either.

## Notes:

1. I am on Linux Mint 21.3 with TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) and kpathsea version 6.3.5.
2. I am using `make4ht` version v0.3m.
3. This is my `config.cfg` file:

```
\RequirePackage{color} 
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{mhchemce}{}{}
\Configure{mhchemcf}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

However, the errors I have noted are reproducible even when the `.cfg` file is excluded from the command, i.e: `make4ht -f odt Manuscript.tex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in TeX4ht. I will fix in the sources. In the meantime, you can use this configuration file:

```
\RequirePackage{color} 
\Preamble{xhtml}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11
\def\:Ttle#1#2#3{%
   \html:addr
   \Get:SecAnchor{#1}{#2}{#3}%
%
   {\escapechar=`\\%
\protect:wrtoc
\csname Modify#1ToToc\endcsname
\protected@edef\:writetoc{\csname if:toc\endcsname{\the\:tokwrite
   {\string\doTocEntry
    \string\toc \expandafter\ifx\csname toToc:#1\endcsname\relax #1\else
       \csname toToc:#1\endcsname\fi
       {#2}{\html:tocsec{\ifx \TocTitle\:UnDef #3\else
       \TocTitle\fi}}{\the\:tokpage}\relax}}}%
 \:writetoc   \global\let\TocTitle\:UnDef
}%
{\csname #1:Href-\endcsname
% %
 \no:lbl:idx \csname Modify#1Title\endcsname
 \html:sectoc{#3}%
 }%
}
\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother
\Configure{mhchemce}{}{}
\Configure{mhchemcf}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This code is from TeX4ht sources, the change is that we use `\protected@edef` instead of `\edef` for :writetoc`, to prevent such errors.

Regarding `_{12}`, you should always use a base for subscripts, so I would write it as:

```
\subsection{B${}_{12}$ in $Persea~americana$}
```

This is the result:

[image]